# non-repeatable read vs. phantom read

Tags: isolation-level, isolation, transaction-isolation

I know that

```
A non-repeatable read occurs, when during the course of a transaction, a row is 
retrieved twice and the values within the row differ between reads.
```

and

```
A phantom read occurs when, in the course of a transaction, two identical queries are executed, and the collection of rows returned by the second query is different from the first.
```

and I guess that this happens because in both causes we are in transaction A and transaction B just commit some changes.

So my question is... Is there another use case from both or 1 that the cause could be another than transaction B just commit some changes while we are in transaction A ? So basically these are 2 different consequences of the same problem, right ?

Comment: Not necessarily

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The discrepancy in a non-repeatable read is always the result of an UPDATE statement, whereas in the case of phantom read, it could also be the result of an INSERT or a DELETE.
Also, the first case can be prevented by locking rows, not the second.